# Using require('...') to dynamically import images in react js not working anymore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, requirejs, create-react-app

I have old projects where this works

```
<img src={require('./logo.svg')} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
```

Bu I created a new project with create-react-app and require('...') no longer works. It's like the new version doesn't support require, so how do i load images dynamically ?

Old project package.json

```
"dependencies": {
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
"@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-dom": "^16.13.1",
"react-scripts": "3.4.3"
}
```

New project package.json

```
"dependencies": {
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
"@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
"react": "^17.0.1",
"react-dom": "^17.0.1",
"react-scripts": "4.0.0",
"web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved it.

requires('...') now returns an object, So your image will be in default key, like below

```
<img src={require('./logo.svg').default} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
```

I don't know why this was changed tho.

Comment: You have updated react-scripts from 3.x to 4.0.0. I noticed the same after upgrade.

Comment: any idea for dynamically image using .map()? works well when i attach image path, but doesn't work when i replace with map item..

Answer (score 0):

You can import an image the following way then

```
import Logo from "./logo.svg";

<img src={Logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
```

Comment: This is for importing one image which is fine, but I'm importing images dynamically with .map().

Comment: Your question does not mention that at all.

Comment: im facing the same issue, not working if using map method...